# How to make an Ableton Live project a set time

Tags: ableton-live

I'd like to make be able a project file only ninety seconds, and have Ableton discard any music that runs over that time as a result of any midi tranformations or effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go into arrange view, expand the master track
   [image]
2. Enter draw mode: press ctrl+b or click on the pencil button at the top of the screen next to the little keyboard. You want it to be yellow.
   [image]
3. Use draw mode to zero out a region of the Master Mixer - Track Volume automation
   [image]
4. Exit draw mode: press ctrl+b again, or click on the pencil button so that it is no longer active.
5. Use the pointer cursor to click on one of the automation corners to the right, deleting it.
   [image]
6. Delete the other rightmost automation corner. Now the automation curve should be down at the bottom for the rest of time.
   [image]

Comment: i'm in arrange view, and can highlight the first 90 seconds and can make that little green arrow, but how do i do the last two steps in your solution?

Comment: I've redone my answer with screenshots.

Comment: So nice to see a cleanly illustrated answer. +1 to you.